# Python - empty range for randrange() (0,0, 0) and ValueError("empty range for randrange() (%d,%d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width))

Tags: python, random, module

When I run this program: (python 3.3.1)

```
import random
import time
from random import randrange
print(' ')
print('I am thinking of a person...')
time.sleep(1)
print('He or she belongs to this group of people:')
people = 'Alice Elise Jack Jill Ricardo David Jane Sacha Thomas'.split()
loop = 0
while loop != 6:
    group = []
    person = randrange(0, len(people))
    personName = people[person]
    int(person)
    group.append(personName)
    del people[person]
    loop = loop + 1
```

I sometimes get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Python\wsda.py", line 132, in <module>
    person = randrange(0, len(people))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\random.py", line 192, in randrange
    raise ValueError("empty range for randrange() (%d,%d, %d)" % (istart, istop,     width))
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (0,0, 0)
```

Basically i want it to get 6 random names from the variable 'people' and add it to the variable 'group'...

Also this is part of a larger program based on the guess who game...
Could someone please tell me how to fix this?
Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error occurs when the `people` list is empty (length 0). You may want to test for that:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.randrange(0, 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Libraries/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 217, in randrange
    raise ValueError, "empty range for randrange() (%d,%d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width)
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (0,0, 0)
```

If you need to add 6 random choices from the `people` list it is better to *shuffle* the `people` list and then add the first 6 of that list to `group`:

```
import random

people = 'Alice Elise Jack Jill Ricardo David Jane Sacha Thomas'.split()
random.shuffle(people)
group.extend(people[:6])
people = people[6:]  # remainder, so the 6 picks have been removed
```

but chances are of course you end up with an empty list again at some point.

Another approach is to just use [`random.sample()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
people = 'Alice Elise Jack Jill Ricardo David Jane Sacha Thomas'.split()
group.extend(random.sample(people, 6))
```

This just picks 6 random names from the list, but leaves `people` unaffected and a future pick of 6 names could repeat names.

Comment: Thx that worked! BTW what does people[:6] do? Does it take the first 6? The division sign is a bit wierd, hence my confusion.

Comment: See [The Python Slice Notation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/509211), it takes the first 6 (indices 0 through to 5).